# Add underscore character prefix to all directories in a directory

Tags: sed, osx, rename

I have several directories within a directory I need renamed to include an underscore "_" character to the beginning of the name.

As a test, I created a parent directory whose contents have three directories:

```
dir1, dir2 and dir3; three files: file1, file2, file3
```

and three dot-prefix files:

```
.file1, .file2, .file3
```

So far, I've tried using `gfind`, after having installed `findutils` on the Mac:

```
gfind . -type d -name '*' -printf "mv \"%h/%f\" \"%h/_%f\"\n" | sh
```

This returns:

```
mv: rename ./. to ./_.: Invalid argument
```

So, I tried using rename with find:

```
find . -type d -exec rename 's/^/_/' {} \;
```

This returns:

```
Can't rename '.' to '_.': Invalid argument
Can't rename './dir1' to '_./dir1': No such file or directory
Can't rename './dir2' to '_./dir2': No such file or directory
Can't rename './dir3' to '_./dir3': No such file or directory
```

Anyone happen to have a viable solution or know where I might be effing up?

Comment: your error msg indicated the issue as well.. find adds `./` to beginning.. so if your rename is perl based, try `rename -n 's|^.*/\K|_|'` and once you are okay with it, remove the `-n` option.. also, can use `+` instead of `\;` similar answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310256/for-all-directories-rename-all-subdirectories-with-a-prefix/310270#310270

Comment: you may also be hitting the problem where you're renaming the parents before the children; look into find -depth

Comment: Since you don't appear to need to recurse into subdirectories, can't you just use a `*/` glob e.g. `for d in */; do echo mv -- "$d" "_$d"; done`

Comment: Why don't you search the [tag:rename] tag, there's plenty of similar questions with answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, you have files and directories like this:

```
$ mkdir dir{1,2,3} ; touch file{1,2,3} .file{1,2,3}
$ ls -A
.file1  .file2  .file3  dir1  dir2  dir3  file1  file2  file3
```

and want to rename the dirs to `_dir1`, `_dir2`, `_dir3`?

That `find`/`printf mv` looks doable. Let's see what it prints:

```
$ find . -type d -name '*' -printf "mv \"%h/%f\" \"%h/_%f\"\n"
mv "./." "./_."
mv "./dir2" "./_dir2"
mv "./dir3" "./_dir3"
mv "./dir1" "./_dir1"
```

That first command will drop an error, since the "dot" is special and you can't rename it. But the others should be ok, and should rename the directories as you wanted:

```
$ find . -type d -name '*' -printf "mv \"%h/%f\" \"%h/_%f\"\n" | sh
mv: cannot move ‘./.’ to ‘./_.’: Device or resource busy
$ ls -d _dir*
_dir1  _dir2  _dir3
```

But piping commands to a shell is a bit ugly, and if the file names are strange enough, the results will be surprising (e.g. if they contain `$` signs which will trigger variable or command substitution in the shell).

If the files are all on one level, then this should do:

```
for x in * ; do [ -d "$x" ] && mv "$x" "_$x" ; done
```

(Though if `_$x` exists already, `$x` will be moved into it.)

If you want to include directories whose names start with a dot, use `shopt -s dotglob` beforehand.

This is close, too:

```
find . -type d -exec rename 's/^/_/' {} \;
```

But since `find` gives `rename` the paths starting with `./`, we need to take that into account. On one level only, this should do (changes the leading `./` to `./_`):

```
find . -type d -exec rename 's,^./,./_,' {} \;
```

To get the directories on all levels, `find -execdir` may be easiest to use. It runs the command in the directory of the file. We need `-depth` to handle the renames in the correct order.

```
find . -depth -type d -execdir rename 's,^./,./_,' {} \;
```

Maybe add `! -name .`, too. e.g.

```
$ mkdir foo foo/dir1 foo/dir2
$ find . -depth \! -name . -type d -execdir rename 's,^./,./_,' {} \;
$ ls  _foo
_dir1  _dir2
```

Comment: ikkachu>  Truly, TRULY appreciate your help.  I've been working on this for the better part of a week.  After looking at this line:
for x in * ; do [ -d "$x" ] && echo mv "$x" "_$x" ; done
I believe I understand it more.  You're assigning the action "x in *" to a variable.  -d is for directories.  Only if that succeeds "&&", echo mv that variable to include the underscore prefix.  What I'm still not quite sure of is why echo needs to be used on mv.

Comment: @lmind, ah, the `echo` was basically just to view the commands before actually executing them, sometimes useful as a sanity check before automating e.g. file removal. Though here, the likely problem would be that the target exists already. And yes, the loop is repeated for all values that the asterisk resolves to. Could have used `if ... ; then ... ; fi` instead of the `&&`. Look here for a guide on shell loops and tests: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, echo isn't necessary, but useful for verbosity?

Comment: @lmind, with the `echo` the `mv` command will not be executed, just displayed. So in a case like this, it's purely a tool for checking correctness before actually doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your first attempt is that you're attempting to rename `.` itself (the current directory), in addition to all the subdirectories. Skip it.

```
gfind . -mindepth 1 -type d -name '*' -printf "mv \"%h/%f\" \"%h/_%f\"\n" | sh
```

But actually, don't do this. never pipe stuff into `sh`. **This doesn't work** unless your file names happen not to contain any shell special characters. If you have a file called `` `rm -r ~` `` (a perfectly valid, if unusual, file name) then pop goes your home directory. Invoke a shell with `-exec` as I show below.

Your second attempt doesn't work because you're inserting the `_` at the beginning of the full path, instead of adding it at the beginning of the base name, i.e. after the last `/`.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -exec rename 's![^/]+$!_$&!' {} \;
```

Neither of these actually work if you have nested directories, because they rename the directories while `find` is traversing them. When you do this, you need to act on the contents of a directory before you act on the directory itself, with the `-depth` option.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -depth -type d -exec rename 's![^/]+$!_$&!' {} \;
```

More portably, call a shell and run `mv`. This works on any POSIX system.

```
find . -depth -type d -name . -o -exec sh -c '
    for d do mv "$d" "${d%/*}/_${d##*/}"; done
' sh {} +
```

If you there are no nested subdirectories, then you can use a simple shell loop. If you don't want to rename directories whose name start with a dot, just use the `*/` wildcard, which only matches directories and symbolic links to directories.

```
for d in */; do
  if [ "$d" = "*/* ] && [ ! -e "$d" ]; then continue; fi   # robustness in case there are no subdirectories
  if [ -L "$d" ]; then continue; fi     # optional: skip symbolic links to directories
  mv -- "$d" "_${d%/}"
done
```

If you want to rename all the directories including the ones whose name starts with a dot, then include the `.*` wildcard as well.

```
for d in .*/ */; do
  if [ "$d" = "*/* ] && [ ! -e "$d" ]; then continue; fi
  if [ -L "$d" ]; then continue; fi
  mv -- "$d" "_${d%/}"
done
```

Note that when you're moving `foo` to `_foo`, if there is already a directory called `_foo`, this moves the old `foo` to `_foo/foo`. To protect against this, add an explicit test.

Or, alternatively, use zsh. It's preinstalled on macOS. First run `autoload -U zmv` (put this in your `.zshrc` or in your script) to load the [`zmv` function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv), then the nonrecursive version (including dot files, excluding symbolic links — `(/D)` is a set of [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers)):

```
zmv -Q '*(/D)' '_$f'
```

or the recursive version (using [modifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) to extract the dirname and the basename):

```
zmv -Q '**/*(/D)' '$f:h/_$f:t'
```

`zmv` will refuse to do a move if the target already exists.